# Interface to have dynamic method names

Tags: java, reflection, enums, interface

Let's say an interface is exposed like this:

```
public interface IAction {
  void run();
  void walk();
  void stop();
  void jump();
}
```

Now like this there can be any number of actions. And each action is associated with an enum type as below:

```
public enum Action {
  RUN("run"),
  WALK("walk"),
  STOP("stop"),
  JUMP("jump")
}
```

Now every time I want to add more actions then I need to add an enum and also associated method in **IAction** interface.

Instead,
Can the interface methods be exposed from the enum anyhow?
And any implementation of the IAction interface should always be dependent on enum **Action**. And all those enum types in **Action** should be exposed. Is this possible?

Comment: Do you plan to have different implementations of `IAction`?

Comment: Let's say I will have only one implementation. Then is it possible? Anyhow for now I am not looking at multiple implementations. I dont think there will be multiple implemtations. This is just a library and the Interface is exposed to clients to use the methods. Implementations are all handled within library.

Comment: If you have only one implementation, than you can set up the implementation in your enum. I will add an answer how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Under the assumption that you only want to have one implementation you can omit the interface and have a `Runnable` in `Action` as follows:

```
public enum Action {
  RUN("run", () -> System.out.println("run")),
  WALK("walk", () -> System.out.println("walk")),
  STOP("stop", () -> System.out.println("stop")),
  JUMP("jump", Action::jump);

  private final String value;
  private final Runnable action;

  Action(final String value, final Runnable action) {
    this.value = value;
    this.action = action;
  }

  public void execute() {
    action.run();
  }

  private static void jump() {
    // TODO: Implement me
  }
```

You can either use lambdas or method references for `Runnable`. A caller executes an action by e.g. `Action.RUN.execute()`.

This way you only have to update this class when adding an action.

This example is an analogy of item 42 in Joshua Bloch's Effective Java, Third Edition.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. But I am not looking for ways to solve. 
I want to know if Java has any support or any means we could achieve method names at the compile time dynamically.

Comment: Then you are probably looking for reflection: https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/javareflection.html

Comment: Fair enough. But with reflections I can invoke method names dynamically. But my ask is to create methods during compile time. Like how a Lombok library generates the methods upon annotation. Likewise I need from the IAction class to generate all possible action methods from Enum types.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand you correctly. With reflection you can iterate over all declared methods of a class.

Comment: How do I declare the methods dynamically? I know this isn’t something which is supported by compiler as per my knowledge. But I just want to know if there is a way to achieve this anyhow.

Comment: If you declare a method dynamically, then how do you implement it?

Comment: Let’s not worry about the implementation. I know it’s little weird what I am asking but I am just trying to figure out.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212575/discussion-between-suman-and-michael-kreutz).